What does the orange icon {;} infront of a network request in Chrome's network panel means? (GA4 hits)
Does anyone know what does this orange icon '{;}' means? I'm looking at a GA4 hit.


That indicates the type of response the request is receiving. {;} in particular means json.
Which makes me think that you're getting some error message there? Normally GA collect requests don't return json.
